# reduce empty spaces in the plot and make the graph fit optimally

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting multiplot with 11 graphs. I given the code used below:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

########################################################################################
#OUTPUT

set size 1.0, 1.0

#POSTCRIPT
set term postscript landscape enhanced color 
set output "radial_distribution_function.ps"    #

#set terminal postscript portrait enhanced color dashed "Helvetica" 8 
#set output "time-density-profile-maltose.ps"

#PNG
#set terminal pngcairo size 650,450 enhanced dash
#set output "multi-plot_gauche_bcMalto-chain2-thermo.png"

# WXT
#set terminal wxt size 900,450 enhanced font 'Arial,10' dashed persist


#set style line 4 lt 4 lw 10    # Please DISABLE pause -1 
#########################################################################
set style line 1 lt 1 lc rgb "#FFB6C1"  lw 2.0  
set style line 2 lt 1 lc rgb "black"    lw 2.0 
set style line 3 lt 1 lc rgb "green"    lw 2.0 
set style line 4 lt 1 lc rgb "blue"     lw 2.0 
set style line 5 lt 1 lc rgb "#8B008B"  lw 2.0
set style line 6 lt 1 lc rgb "yellow"   lw 2.0
#########################################################################


### START MARCRO
set macro
#ylabelFONT="font 'Arial,16'"
labelFONT="font 'Arial,12'"
scaleFONT="font 'Arial,12'"
keyFONT="font 'Arial,14'"
#graph="using 1:2 with lines lw 1   "
scaleFONT2="font 'Arial,11'"
### END MACRO


set key font ",8"
set key spacing 0.7
unset key
set autoscale                           # scale axes automatically
set xtic auto                        @scaleFONT     # set xtics automatically
set ytic auto                        @scaleFONT     # set ytics automatically
set xlabel "Distance (Angstrom)"    @labelFONT
set ylabel "g(r)"           @labelFONT
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:5]
#set title "Density profile for isomaltose"


set multiplot layout 4,3 title ""


# PLOT_1
set label "(a) O11" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O11-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O11-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O11-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O11-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O11-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O11-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"


# PLOT_2
unset label
set label "(b) O12" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O12-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O12-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O12-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O12-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O12-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O12-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"

# PLOT_3
unset label
set label "(c) O13" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT 
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O13-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O13-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O13-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O13-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O13-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O13-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"

# PLOT_4
unset label
set label "(d) O14" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O14-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O14-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O14-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O14-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O14-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O14-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"



# PLOT_5
unset label
set label "(e) O15" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT 
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O15-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O15-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O15-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O15-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O15-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O15-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"

# PLOT_6
unset label
set label "(f) O16" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O16-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O16-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O16-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O16-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O16-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O16-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"



# PLOT_7
unset label
set label "(g) O22" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT 
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O22-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O22-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O22-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O22-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O22-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O22-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"

# PLOT_8
unset label
set label "(h) O23" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O23-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O23-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O23-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O23-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O23-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O23-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"



# PLOT_9
unset label
set label "(i) O24" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT 
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O24-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O24-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O24-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O24-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O24-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O24-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"

# PLOT_10
unset label
set label "(j) O25" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O25-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O25-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O25-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O25-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O25-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O25-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"



# PLOT_11
unset label
set label "(k) O26" at 1.5, 4   @labelFONT
unset key 
plot    "maltoLyo12per-ddm_O26-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 1 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}12%H_{2}O",\
    "maltoLyo23per-ddm_O26-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 2 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}23%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_O26-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 3 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_O26-wat_O.dat"    using 1:2 w l ls 4 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(S)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMR_O26-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 5 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(R)25%H_{2}O",\
    "bchainRS25per-BMS_O26-wat_O.dat"   using 1:2 w l ls 6 title "{/Symbol b}Mal-C_{12}C_{8}(RS)(S)25%H_{2}O"

unset multiplot
```

The graph that I get is show here [image]

What I notice from the graph is there is lot of empty space between the graphs. For example between graph (a) and (b) and also between graph (a) and (d). I want to reduce the space between them and make the graph little bigger.

What I should do to reduce the space and optimize the graph size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, lets start :)

First, your script and your naming of the data files is perfect for iterations. So, you can define a list of file name templates with a placeholder `%s`, which is later substituted by the actual parameter.

So you first have an iteration over the different `O11`, `O12` etc. values and for each of those a new plot is generated. Then you have a `plot for` iteration over the file names which are all placed in a single plot.

Using `set linetype` to define the colors allows you to make use of the automatic line type increment.

Now to your actual question:

I think the best options are to correct the offset of the labels a bit, e.g. with

```
set ylabel "g(r)" offset 1,0  @labelFONT
```

which shifts the ylabel by one character unit to the right with respect to the automatically selected position. That should give you a little bigger graph.

If that isn't enough you must start to manually set the margins. I would start by changing only the top and right margins. With e.g.

```
set tmargin 0
set rmargin 0
```

the top and right margins will be placed at the boundaries of the respective panels. With e.g. `set rmargin 0.5` the right margin is set to a half character width. You must play around with these values.

Here is a shortened script. Note, that I couldn't test it, because I don't have the data files. I hope I didn't make any errors :)

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set term postscript landscape enhanced color 
set output "radial_distribution_function.ps"    #

#########################################################################
set linetype 1 lt 1 lc rgb "#FFB6C1"  lw 2.0  
set linetype 2 lt 1 lc rgb "black"    lw 2.0 
set linetype 3 lt 1 lc rgb "green"    lw 2.0 
set linetype 4 lt 1 lc rgb "blue"     lw 2.0 
set linetype 5 lt 1 lc rgb "#8B008B"  lw 2.0
set linetype 6 lt 1 lc rgb "yellow"   lw 2.0
#########################################################################

set macro
labelFONT="font 'Arial,12'"
scaleFONT="font 'Arial,12'"
keyFONT="font 'Arial,14'"
scaleFONT2="font 'Arial,11'"

unset key
set autoscale                           # scale axes automatically
set xtic auto                        @scaleFONT     # set xtics automatically
set ytic auto                        @scaleFONT     # set ytics automatically
set xlabel "Distance (Angstrom)"     @labelFONT
set ylabel "g(r)"  offset 1,0        @labelFONT
set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:5]

file_tmpls = "maltoLyo12per-ddm_%s-wat_O.dat ".\
             "maltoLyo23per-ddm_%s-wat_O.dat ".\
             "bcmLyo25perR-BMR_%s-wat_O.dat ".\
             "bcmLyo25perS-BCS_%s-wat_O.dat ".\
             "bchainRS25per-BMR_%s-wat_O.dat ".\
             "bchainRS25per-BMS_%s-wat_O.dat "

par = "O11 O12 O13 O14 O15 O16 O22 O23 O24 O25 O26"
labels = "a b c d e f g h i j k"
label_tmpl = "(%s) %s"

# You must optimize the values, which are given in units of character widths (or heights)
set tmargin 0.5
set rmargin 0.5
#set lmargin 2
#set bmargin 2

set multiplot layout 4,3 title ""

do for [i=1:words(par)] {

    set label 1 sprintf("(%s) %s", word(labels, i), word(par, i)) at 1.5, 4 @labelFONT

    plot for [f in file_tmpls] sprintf(f, word(par, i)) using 1:2 w l

}
unset multiplot
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the code you have modified. It worked. But what I can see is the labels (b),(c) and others actually overlap one another start from label (b). Further I want the legend possibly placed to the at right corner below. (next to figure (k)). Since the loop is new for me I have to ask this. Thank you.

Comment: Concerning the label, I had forgotten to add an explicit label tag `set label 1 ...`, so that the label is overwritten in every plot. About the key, I have to think about this later ;)